# C#, how to use IEnumerator in a user defined class

Tags: c#

I have a collection class which contains 1 property - an array of a sub class.

For the sake of the question. I have a basket class, then fruits[] as the one property of basket. The fruit class contains 3 properties for example. Name, Color and Size.

How can I make the basket class behave so that I can use foreach loops on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this simple case, you can delegate the enumeration to the array, like this:

```
public class Basket: IEnumerable {
  private Fruit[] fruits;

  public IEnumerator getEnumerator() {
    return fruits.GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using the generic IEnumerator<Fruit>, although the array would have to be cast to an IEnumerable<Fruit> to do so

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing the generic one. However, then you need two `GetEnumerator` implementations (the non-generic one as explicit interface implementations, the generic one one implicit), which may be somewhat confusing as it adds some noise. But you are right, nowadays one should implement the generic interface in production code.

Answer (score 4):

From what you've got already, you're able to do this:

```
foreach(fruit f in myBasket.fruits) { ... }
```

is that not good enough? if you want to use `foreach(fruit f in myBasket)`, you could implement `IEnumerable`, and in your `getEnumerator` method just bubble the call to `fruits.getEnumerator`, but really, I think in that case I would rather have basket inherit a list of fruit:

```
public class Basket : List<Fruit>() { ... }
```

and then you would not use the private member `fruits` at all.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst it may be more desirable to derive from `List<Fruit>` here is something to get you started if for some reason that does not suit your requirements:-

```
public class Basket : IEnumerable<Fruit>
{
     private Fruit[] myFruit;

     public int Count { get; private set; }

     public IEnumerator<Fruit> GetEnumerator()
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
           yield return myFruit[i];
     }
     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
     {
       return GetEnumerator();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322022